# Synonym request for [tokbox] and [opentok]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I work for TokBox, and I think it would help both the StackOverflow community and my company if these two tags became synonyms.

We send a good amount of our customers over to StackOverflow to ask technical questions because we believe in the power/ability of the community there. This also means that we participate to try and answer any questions we can. At TokBox we only work on one product, the OpenTok Platform. So when anyone asks a question about either [tokbox](/questions/tagged/tokbox) or [opentok](/questions/tagged/opentok) they are really asking about the same thing. It would make it much easier for us to get to questions and for our customers who ask them to get answers more quickly if we could treat the two tags as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hesitant to do this for a couple of reasons.

1. Synonyms should only be created when two tags mean *exactly* the same thing.  While that may be nearly true today, it wouldn't be true if your company ever released a new product.
2. There are very few questions with either tag. It would be easy for you and your co-workers to follow both tags and retag questions appropriately (by either adding the product tag, removing the company tag, or both).

Compare with [apache](/questions/tagged/apache), [mozilla](/questions/tagged/mozilla), [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft), [google](/questions/tagged/google), [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), and [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter).  They all have generic organization name tags, plus several more specific tags for various programming tools and APIs.

---

Side Note: I see a lot of the same people asking/answering questions for your tags, which shows that at least a few different people from your company are interested in engaging your users on Stack Overflow.  Thanks for doing this!  You're doing a better job of it than some of the companies I listed above.  I'm sure your users appreciate it.  :)

Comment: Great points. I didn't realize that I had the ability to retag questions until just now. The plan moving forward will be to retag [tokbox] questions as [opentok]. Unfortunately this means we will have to monitor both, but as you mentioned in (1) this may be the best thing for the long term. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Ankur It's not that hard to monitor both tags. You can search for questions that have either tag using this query: [`[tokbox] [or] [opentok]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tokbox+or+opentok). And then sort by "newest", "unanswered", or however you like.